# JS cannot get value new variable in Eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I am doing firefox add-ons development right now, and i have a problem to get value of `nums` variable in the eval  (reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools.inspectedWindow/eval)

here is my following code :

```
browser.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("var nums = prompt('Numbers');")
                .then(function (result, isException) {

                });
console.log(nums);
```

here the console log give me result :

```
ReferenceError: nums is not defined
```

any solution for this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Uh, you are evaluating the declaration inside the inspected window context, why do you expect it to exist outside in your addon context?

Comment: yes ... actually i want showing prompt into browser .. but it's already solved sir .. so yesterday i just added null global variable and override variable in the eval and get value from `result` parameter..